# Google Calendar API update does not return error for deleted events

Tags: php, api, calendar

I am using Google Calendar APIv3 and were successful at capturing error while trying to [delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/delete) an item that were already deleted in Google Calendar. I am using the same try-catch method for the two processes, but when I'm trying to [update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) an event that was also deleted in Calendar side, I receive no error. I tried to find answer from the poorly documented [Google Devs site](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#exponential-backoff), but without result. I think at least one of the below should throw a Google_Service_Exception in case of an eventID referring to a deleted event;

```
$event = $service->events->get($calendarID, $eventID);
(...)
$event = $service->events->update($calendarID, $eventID, $event);
```

So my question is whether the above PHP code should return an error object if the event with the parameter eventID was already deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that an event that is deleted from Google Calendar does not get deleted in the traditional sense; the "*status*" attribute of the event changes to "*cancelled*", but this does not **always** result in exception while getting or updating an event, only when trying to delete it. See *status* property at [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events).